# Viewing nodes of a kd-tree in Python

Tags: python, kdtree

i have used the following code to construct a kd-tree using python

```
import random 
import kdtree
from kdtree import KDTree
import itertools
def method(size, min_, max_):
            range1 = range(min_, max_)
            range2= range(min_, max_)
            points = itertools.product(range1, range2)
            return random.sample(list(points), size)
x=method(500,0,360)
tree = KDTree.construct_from_data(x)
```

i have used

```
dir(tree)
```

and got its attributes. 
how do  i see the nodes of the tree?

Comment: The tree may be implemented in a non-materialized form to save memory and improve performance. Plus, even when materialized, it may be in low-level C structures for performance reasons. **Have you looked at the source?** This isn't a black box, but open source, after all.